# HP laser jet M404dn

Tags: linux-mint, printer, hp

I have an HP Laser Jet M404 DN printer (USB not Wireless). The printer shows up in the printer memory. It will print a test page from there and will print from emails but won't print anything from LibreOffice. I have Linux Mint Tricia. I'm a complete novice and have no idea what I'm doing. I had exactly the same problem with a Canon PIXMA.

Comment: Have you tried [HPLIP](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip)? Your printer is [supported](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index).

Comment: Do I just press the download at the top?  My printer is there.  Please forgive me, I really know zilch

Comment: Select "Linux Mint" and press the "Download HPLIP" button and download the "run" file.
Then follow the [instructions](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/install/index).

Comment: thank you Freddy. I'll try that now

Comment: It's still says it's downloading , after 25 minutes.  Although the blue line is right across.  Should I just wait ?  It has appeared in the download menu

Comment: It now says there's an error downloading. I have a screenshot, but don't know how to attach

Comment: You can try a different download mirror, e.g. [here](https://sourceforge.net/settings/mirror_choices?projectname=hplip&filename=hplip/3.20.11/hplip-3.20.11.run&selected=netcologne).

Comment: I've tried that and this message appeared The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file, you could corrupt this document.
You can also choose another character encoding and try again.

Comment: It worked Freddy, after I clicked 'edit anyway'  It won't print duplex, but at least it prints.  Thank you so very much for your help!

Comment: Don't open the file with an editor. You need to open a terminal, `cd` to to the download location and run the file, e.g. `cd ~/Downloads; sh hplip-3.20.11.run`.

Comment: @Freddy or Madwoman, would either of you like to provide a proper Answer to this question? As-is, it's seen as "unanswered" by the SE system since it was resolved in the comments. Thank you!